# How to determine distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, order-theory

I hope you will be patient with the inarticulate question of a non-mathematician. It's hard to get an answer when you don't even know how to ask the question. But here goes...

...Actually, I have two distinct but related questions. Firstly, I should like to be able to put a 'score' on how well a series of points on a line are distributed between the beginning and the end. So, if the points were clumped together rather than being well spread along the line the score would be **low**. And, conversely, if the points are well distributed the score would be **high**.

Secondly, I should also like to do the same for a series of points inside a triangle. So, how can I produce an effective measure of how well the points are distributed within the triangle?

Is there an algorithm/formula that would do this? I'm very conscious that I have given a very poor explanation of what I am looking for.

**Edited**

Could the [Kolmogorov–Smirnov test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test) be a good measure of how evenly points are distributed along a line?

Comment: Maybe this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodness_of_fit can help?

Answer (score 1):

This is not really an answer but an extended comment in hope to point you in the right direction. I'm sure others can help more so this is a **community wiki**, feel free to edit.

For simplicity let's assume you always have a fixed number of points, $N$. 
In your first case, let's also assume without any loss of generality  points are between zero and one. A "distribution" in this case is just a $N$-vector $x=[x_1,x_2,...,x_N]$ where $x_1$ is the location of the smallest point, $x_2$ is the location of the second smallest point, and so on. You are looking for an **order** to measure the clumpiness/concentration of two different distributions. You are likely to found many, some may better reflect what you really want than others. Some examples are:

1. the variance (how far away from the mean they are)
2. majorization [[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majorization]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majorization%5d) (we use it in economics to measure income inequality,we call it Lorenz order)
3. An *ad-hoc* idea (that also works in 2-dimensions) that probably must have already been formalized elsewhere is this: pick any small number $\varepsilon >0$ and count what is the minimum number of balls of radius $\varepsilon$ that you need to cover your set of points, $x_1,...x_N$. Call this number: $\texttt{clumps}(x,\varepsilon)$. If for other set of points, $y_1$,...,$y_N$ you have $\texttt{clumps}(x,\varepsilon)>\texttt{clumps}(y,\varepsilon)$, we say $y$ is more concentrated and $x$ is more dispersed. If there is a tie, then increase $\varepsilon$ until the tie is broken.